# React 18's StrictMode: Best Approach for Making API Requests on Mount

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React 18 and I want to make an API request whenever the component mounts. However, when I use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array, it hits my API endpoint twice. I understand this is due to React strict mode, and I've read that it's not advisable to remove it.

I can achieve this by using the following approach, but is there a better method?

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const shouldRun = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldRun.current) {
      shouldRun.current = false;
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json));
    }
  }, []);
  return <></>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: If it's a get, why not just hit it twice? It only happens in Dev.